# NSTextContainer exclusionPaths setter unrecognised?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Sorry if the question looks trivial:

I'm trying to set a `NSTextContainer` instance property `exclusionPaths` using its underlying setter: `[myNSTCInstance setExclusionPaths:arrayOfPaths];` and I systematically get:

> `-[NSTextContainer setExclusionPaths:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12b8410"`

Since (for some reasons) I can't use the dot notation `myNSTCInstance.exclusionPaths =`, I was wondering how to set this property the more classic way?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NSTextContainer` on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSTextContainer_Class_TextKit/Reference/Reference.html) has a `exclusionPaths` property, but
[`NSTextContainer` on OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextContainer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does *not* have this property. 
According to the documentation, you have to subclass `NSTextContainer` on OS X to define
non-rectangular regions.

Comment: Oh yes absolutely. I haven't figured out the docs were saying "NSTextContainer for iOS". Too bad OS X NSTextContainer doesn't provide such a mechanism. My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There are no reason that this does'n work. `exclusionPaths` is a property of `NSTextContainer` class.

1. Are you sure that your object is of type `NSTextContainer` ?
2. If Yes, try to remove your derived Data and relaunch Xcode.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. But as Martin R pointed out, NSTextContainer doesn't provide such a property for OS X. Only for iOS. Thank you.